# Parse a text file and add entries to a table

Tags: bash, parsing

I'd like to parse the following in a text file using bash/sh:

```
Title1-abc
Title2-123
address111 code111
address222 code222
(...)

Title1-xyz
Title2-qwe
addressxxx codexxx
addressyyy codeyyy
(...)

Title1-...
(...)
```

Into a table

```
Title        Title2        Addresses    Code
Title1-abc   Title2-123    address111   code111
Title1-abc   Title2-123    address222   code222
Title1-xyz   Title2-qwe    addressxxx   codexxx
Title1-xyz   Title2-qwe    addressyyy   codeyyy
(...)
```

What would be the simplest way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

This `awk` script uses two variables to store the block's two title lines, then iterates over the subsequent lines until the next empty row:

```sh
awk -vOFS="\t" '{if (NF==0) {t1=""; t2=""} else {
  if (t1=="") {t1=$0; getline t2} else print t1,t2,$1,$2
}}'
```

```
Title1-abc  Title2-123  address111  code111
Title1-abc  Title2-123  address222  code222
Title1-xyz  Title2-qwe  addressxxx  codexxx
Title1-xyz  Title2-qwe  addressyyy  codeyyy
```